# How to integrate ckeditor plugin with WYSIWYG module

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I want to use http://ckeditor.com/demo#table-resizer addon for my drupal site which uses WYSIWYG drupal module and "CKEditor" as its editor.

I have tried using hook_wysiwyg_plugin() hook but I am not able to get it working. 
Following is my code for the plugin hook.

```
function mymodule_wysiwyg_plugin($editor, $version) {
  switch ($editor) {
    case 'ckeditor':
      return array(
        'tableresize' => array(
          'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/plugins/tableresize',
          'filename' => 'plugin.js',
          'load' => TRUE,
        ),
      );
      break;
    }
}
```

In the code above, plugin.js is the javascript addon file from CKEditor.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What are the versions of Drupal and WYSIWYG module?